# Two-way binding for UITextField.text not updating

Tags: c#, ios, mvvmcross

When I change the content of an UITextField.Text "by hand", the change is not reflected to the viewmodel - the setter method is not called.

In my view model

```
private string _amount;
public string Amount
{
  get { return _amount; }
  set { _amount = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Amount); }
}
```

In my view

```
var _amount = new UITextField() { TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false };
View.AddSubview(_amount);
var set = this.CreateBindingSet<View, core.ViewModels.ViewModel>();
set.Bind(_amount).To(vm => vm.Amount);
set.Apply();
_amount.Text = "something";
```

Amount in the viewmodel is not updated, but if I type "something" into this textfield, then the viewmodel is updated.

I tried

```
_amount.WillChangeValue("Text");
_amount.Text = "something";
_amount.DidChangeValue("Text");
```

but that did'nt work.

How do can the view tell mvvmcross that the field is updated?

Edit: Solved by a custom binding listening on UITextField changes via an observer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MvvmCross binds to `Text` using the delegate/event `EditingChanged` from objC - see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/v3.1/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Touch/Target/MvxUITextFieldTextTargetBinding.cs#L54 - this is why no event fires when you change the text.

One way around this could be to use an inherited control and a new property instead - e.g.

```
 [Register("MyTextField")]
 public class MyTextField : UITextField
 {
     public MyTextField() {
        HookEvent();
     }

     public MyTextField(IntPtr ptr) {
        HookEvent();
     }

     // other ctors as needed

     private void HookEvent() {
        EditingChanged += (s, e) => MyTextChanged.Raise(this);
     }

     public string MyText {
        get { return Text; }
        set { Text = value; MyTextChanged.Raise(this); }
     }

     public event EventHandler MyTextChanged;
 }
```

This would allow you to use `MyTextField` in place of `UITextField` and `MyText` in place of `Text`

Comment: Ahh - EditingChanged. But - Raise() is not defined on Eventhandler?

I was thinking - maybe I should be looking at a custom binding instead?

Comment: The custom binding works like a charm. I just Observe the Text property, and uses that to FireValueChanged.

Comment: @larswolff any chance you could share the code that fixed this?